# Colab - Box for input() in python code too long so I need to scroll back to read the question

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I plan to use colab notebooks to teach my pupils (12-13 year olds) Python.  We will start with using input() and display with print() to ask simple questions and display the answer.

One problem I have come across is when I use input() in a code cell with an input string a really long input box is produced (in the output area) to get the input value.  It is so long that the window scrolls to the end of this empty input box, and you have to scroll back to read the question, even when the window is at full screen width .  This is really strange as the input box is completely empty does not need to to be bigger than the window or frame.

Are there settings I can change to prevent this or can I do something with the css to reduce the size of this input box?

This may seem a trivial problem, but little things like this can be distracting and add to the frustration of learning the language so I would like to prevent it if I can.

I have attached a picture that shows the problem.
[picture that shows the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvybr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the problem you are trying to solve.  Colab fits inside my window perfectly when I size the window to full screen.  I think this might be a problem with your browser.  Are you using the latest version of Firefox or Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. For me, it was because I was plotting a graph using the `matplotlib.pyplot` library before prompting for the input. After I removed that, it worked just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It seems that Colab spans the text box according to the width of the navigator, by default, without taking into acount the length of the prompt. Therefore, a very simple workaround is to insert a newline character at the end of the prompt:

```
input('Prompt text:\n')  # instead of input('Prompt text:')
```

This way, the text box appears below the prompt text, spanning no more than the window's width (except for a minimum width)